# How to pass kernel modules to initramfs

Tags: drivers, kernel

everyone.

I need to add the kernel modules for Nvidia, like

`nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm`

and regenerate initramfs after. I know how to do this with `mkinitcpio` but couldn't find the correspondent method on Ubuntu. What file do I need to edit with syntax and how to regenerate after?

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate initramfs by

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

You can add modules to `/etc/modules` file.

But it looks like you are doing something wrong, since this is done automatically when you install drivers.

Comment: Even these additional modules I said in the post? I'm trying to fix an issue where the screen returns broken from suspend. On Arch-based systems I can do this with early loading of Nvidia drivers like above.